# Kreyszig, Introduction Functinal Analysis... Page 19

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

How about $X=[-1,2]$, then $X$ closed set. Does $X$ still belong to $F$?
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: So $F$ is the collection of opens in $X$. How is such an open defined? The answer should be yes, yes $X$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you know definition open set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Many of us went through this I guess... You think that $-1$ and $2$ are not interior points of $X$ and therefore you conclude that $X$ is not open right?

Let's get back to the definition. Let $(X, d) $ be a metric space. An open ball $B(x, \epsilon) $ is defined as:
$$B(x, \epsilon)=\{z\in X\ : \ d(x, z) <\epsilon\} $$
Now take$X=[-1,2]$ and  the euclidean metric a ball around $2$ is:
\begin{align} 
B(2, \epsilon)=\{z\in [-1,2]\ :\  |z-2|<\epsilon\}
\end{align} 
AND NOT
\begin{align} 
\color{red} {B(2, \epsilon)\neq\{z\in \mathbb R \ : \ |z-2|<\epsilon\}} 
\end{align} 
Now figure out what $\epsilon $ you must take so that $B(2,\epsilon)\subset X$.

**Final note.** all balls are in the metric space you are working with!

Comment: Good point!
 so you mean that $X=[-1,2]$ is an open set?

Comment: @MHYip yes an open set in $X$

Comment: I know that there is at least an open set in $X$. And I follow the definition of an open set, I have to agree with you. But I still can't believe that $X$ itself is an open set. It is so different to what I have learned at High school about open interval and closed interval. So, do you really mean that $X$ itself is an open set, even $X$ is given as a closed set?  Can you give me a simple and instructive case that the set in not an open set. Thank you for helping, I hope it doesn't bother you too much.

Comment: @MHYip you are mixing everything up a little bit. Okay when talking about the metric space $X=[-1,2]$ forget everything about  $\mathbb R$. You only have $X$ and NOTHING ELSE. Everything you have lives in $X$ there is no such thing as the number $14$ or  something. So ONLY $X$! How do you prove that $X$ is open? You must find a ball for each point in $X$ that is contained in $X$. You can find such ball because EVERY BALL is in $X$. So $X$ is open in itself.

Comment: @MHYip it is also closed. Why? Because the complement is the empty set and the empty set is open. Hence $X$ is also closed. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, It is crystal clear now. Thank you :D

Answer (score -1):

$(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{T}_\mathbb{R})$ is a topological space, where $\mathscr{T}_\mathbb{R}$ contains the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in the sense that you are probably used to. Now $X=[-1,2]\subset \mathbb{R}$, inherets a  topology $\mathscr{T}_{X}$ (called the *subspace topology*) from $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{T}_\mathbb{R})$ which is defined by
$$ A \in \mathscr{T}_{X} \Leftrightarrow  A = X\cap U \text{ for some } U \in \mathscr{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$$
Now obviously $X = X \cap \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R }\in \mathscr{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$, thus $X \in \mathscr{T}_{X}$, which means it is open (in itself).